# Pass a Boolean Parameter Value to Field Boolean Express for Row Visibility/Return

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a field expression in my SSRS report that generates a true or false based on an IFF statement. I would like to pass a Boolean parameter value to drive a row suppression/row return if it matches the Boolean field expression value.

If the parameter is true then look to see if expression is true, show rows that are matching.

Thank you,
Erin

Comment: This is neither a question nor is any source of what you attempted provided.

Answer (score 0):

You want to only display rows where a parameter matches a field in your dataset - both of which happen to be **Boolean**.

In the **Row Visibility** of the table, Select **Show or Hide based on expression**. For the expression, you'll want something like:

```
=NOT(Parameters!TFParameter.Value = Fields!TFField.Value)
```

This will check to see if the Boolean values match and if so return FALSE (since the badly worded **Show or Hide** is really **HIDE**)
Your field and parameter names will be different.

If both the parameter and field are FALSE, the records will be displayed. If you only want it displayed when both are TRUE, use

```
=NOT(Parameters!TFParameter.Value = Fields!TFField.Value AND Fields!TFField.Value - True)
```

Comment: So based on what the user selects (True/False/Null), I would like the report to filter results based on expression values - this is not a field value per se.  Parameter = True/False/Null and the Expression =iif(COUNT(iif(Fields!sReqStatusName.Value="Not Met",1,nothing))=0, True, False)

Answer (score -1):

=iif(IsNothing(Parameters!RequirementsMet.Value),false, iif(COUNT(iif(Fields!sReqStatusName.Value="Not Met",1,nothing))= 0, False =(Parameters!RequirementsMet.Value), True = (Parameters!RequirementsMet.Value)))